# spark streaming aggreagte data based on the time window with json data from kafka

Tags: json, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-kafka

### The goal To achieve:

spark-streaming  aggreagte  json data from kafka, then do some calculation based  this data  with TimeWindow(1m,1hour)

### the solution I'm trying:

1. use sqlcontext  convert json data  and do the  aggreagte,  it'll return a rdd as dstream
2. use reducebykeyandwindow to achieve the calculation by time window with returned  dstream

### The problems:

1. i do not konw how to return dataframe as dstream rdd
2. is there other way to  do the  time window based  cumulative calculation

**the part of code is below:**

```
 val sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(ssc.sparkContext)
 import sqlContext.implicits._

 val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicpMap).map(_._2)
/*  kafkaStream data  is json array like below
  [{"metric":"access","host":"10.1.2.3","Num1":80.0,"Num2":90.0},
  {"metric":"access","host":"10.1.2.3","Num1":90.0,"Num2":200.0}]
*/

/* kafkaStream  convert json data as dataframe  and do some  transformers */
var aggdata = kafkaStream.transform( rdd => {
    if (rdd.count > 0) {
      val dataframe = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)
      var returndf = dataframe.groupBy($"host",$"metric").agg(sum($"Num1"),sum($"Num2"),sum($"Num1")/sum($"Num2"))
      /* returndf.show()         
        +--------+------+---------+---------+-----------------------+ 
        |    host|metric|sum(Num1)|sum(Num2)|(sum(Num1) / sum(Num2))|
        +--------+------+---------+---------+-----------------------+
        |10.1.2.3|access|    170.0|    290.0|     0.5862068965517241|
        +--------+------+---------+---------+-----------------------+
      */
      returndf  // should return an rdd as dstream   (Problem 1)
    } else {
        rdd.map(l => ("" -> ""))  //should return empty rdd as dstream (Problem 1)  
    }
}) 
/* do redcue by time window 
        +--------+------+---------+---------+-----------------------+
        |    host|metric|sum(Num1)|sum(Num2)|(sum(Num1) / sum(Num2))|
        +--------+------+---------+---------+-----------------------+
time1   |10.1.2.3|access|    170.0|    290.0|     0.5862068965517241|
        +--------+------+---------+---------+-----------------------+
time2   |10.1.2.3|access|    200.0|    300.0|     0.5862068965517241|

*/
window1min=aggdata.reducebykeyandwindow(xxxx)
/*  window1min data shoube time1 data  +  time2 data  +timeN data 
        +--------+------+---------+---------+-----------------------+
        |    host|metric|sum(Num1)|sum(Num2)|(sum(Num1) / sum(Num2))|
        +--------+------+---------+---------+-----------------------+
        |10.1.2.3|access|    370.0|    590.0|     0.5862068965517241|
        +--------+------+---------+---------+-----------------------+
*/
```

### THIS IS UPDATE 1 (I guess  i am  get close  to the  goal)

1. on top of class get an case class

   case class Status(avg:Double = 0.0, count:Double = 0)
2. make dataframe  return  a right type of rdd .

   ```
   var aggdata = kafkaStream.transform( rdd => {
           var returndata: RDD[(String,Status)] = 
           if (!rdd.isEmpty) {
               val dataframe = sqlContext.read.json.read.json(rdd).filter("tags.type in ('avgms','gt20ms')")
               val report = dataframe.groupBy($"host",$"metric").agg(sum($"Num1"),sum($"Num2"))
               report.map(r=> (r(0).toString -> Status(r(1).toString.toDouble),Status(r(2).toString.toDouble))).rdd
           } else {
               rdd.map(l => ("" -> Status()))
           }
           returndata
       }
   ```

   aggdata.print()

**ps: sorry my english is poor,If have any misunderstand of here , fell free to ask, 欢迎使用中文**.

Comment: If your source is Kafka,why dont you use Spark-Streaming for this, it will return DStream, then you can do the window aggregate operations on DStream.

Comment: i am not sure what do you mean ,but below is the code,
inline  
`val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicpMap).map(_._2)
kafkaStream.reduceByKeyAndWindow((mapfun), Seconds(30), Seconds(10))`

Comment: Yes, you can look into this http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations

Comment: If  direct use reduceByKeyAndWindow with  dstream, in  1m  time window  it will  stacke  a  large json data,  i think this  will slowdown the data  processing,  another reason is that some of the more complex aggreagte operation  spark.sql  is much more easier to  achieve

Comment: Yes i agree, you can do lot of operations once you create DF from RDD.